# Spotify: Passing SpotifyAppRemote Between Activities

Tags: java, android

## MainActivity

I have my application setup to where on the home screen it updates what is currently playing (name and artist picture) and other options avalible to the user. But when a user wants to dive more in depth to what they listening they launch a new activity.

Below snippet of code is how I init a new remote instance and disconnecting from it once the life cycle gets to onStop().

```java
@Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        /* To prevent multiple instances of app remote being active. */
        SpotifyAppRemote.disconnect(mSpotifyAppRemote);

        /* Connect to SpotifyAppRemote */
        SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams, new Connector.ConnectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
                mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
                Log.d(TAG, "App remote Connected!");
                connected();
            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
        }
    });
}


@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        /* When app not in use, disconnect. */
        SpotifyAppRemote.disconnect(mSpotifyAppRemote);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: App remote disconnected");
    }
```

## CurrentlyPlaying

Where it displays more information on the currently playing track (Audio analysis and cover art for the track). I send fetched audio analysis data stored in and object (from MainActivity) and pass it to the CurrentlyPlaying activity, then update the UI with the stats.

## Question

Would it be smart to continue to use the SpotifyAppRemote that was initially created and pass that between new activities and back (this arises a new task to write something that allows the remote itself to be passed between activities)? Or, should I disconnect from the remote when a new activity starts and then recreate the remote in that activity? I can see how this will slow down performance and fluidity.

If there are other suggestions I would greatly appreciation any insight.

Comment: how are you fetching and showing cover art for the track?